# Using daemon threads in a Java threadpool is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a Java threadpool created via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` that I want to use daemon threads.

The reason is that this is a GUI app and I don't want these threads to cause the program to stay running after the Window is closed.

I implemented a custom `ThreadFactory` that sets `Thread.setDaemon(true)` on the threads it creates.

The class is this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class DaemonThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{

    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable){
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    }

}
```

For some reason when I use `DaemonThreadFactory` with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` none of my queued tasks are executed. If I change it back to regular `ThreadFactory` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing the `Runnable` to the thread, so there's no code to execute:

```
@Override
public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    return thread;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are ignoring the Runnable passed to you which the Thread must wrap.

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
```

otherwise you are creating threads which literally do nothing.